Is there a way to dynamically set the LambdaFunction Role property?
We have a product that we're developing that uses AWS Lambda Annotations Framework, using C# for writing the Lambda functions and handlers.
We have Dev, QA, and Production stages that we are deploying our Lambdas to.
Is there a way to dynamically assign the role in the LambdaFunction attribute of a function handler?
For example: assuming the ARN for dev is "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/my_role", and the ARN for QA is "arn:aws:iam::987654321:role/my_role",
how would I go about dynamically changing the value assigned to the Role property in the following code block
using Amazon.Lambda.Annotations.APIGateway;
using Amazon.Lambda.Annotations;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using MyCompany.Lambdas.Interfaces;

namespace MyCompany.Lambdas.Serverless.Endpoints;

public class DataLambdas 
{
    IMyService myService;
    
    public DataLambdas(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    [LambdaFunction(Role = "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/my_role", ResourceName = "GetData")]
    [HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/data")]
    public async Task<string> GetData(ILambdaContext lambdaContext) => await myService.GetData(lambdaContext);  
}

so that I could have the role change based on which build configuration I'm using, and therefore the stage I'm intending to deploy my Lambda functions to?
I've tried creating a class that could be instantiated to get the role from an appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.QA.json, or appsettings.Production.json file, based on conditional directives, but Visual Studio keeps complaining. My guess is that the attribute has to be set at design-time and that trying to access a property of a class instance isn't possible in this case.
I also tried setting it to something like Role = "@my_role" (using the technique shown in the readme here) and then in the CloudFormation template file added the lines under the Role property as shown here
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
...
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "my_role",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
...

but it gave me design-time errors stating "my_role is an unknown resource for this template" and "Arn is an unknown attribute for this resource".

I'm looking for this too, and the closest I came across is this reference: essentially you put a placeholder for the role to refer to another resource you can declare in your cloudformation template.  So not directly injectable, but...there might be a way to do it with CDK or ServerlessFramework etc?

Some CloudFormation properties are not set to a specific value but instead reference another resource or parameter defined in the CloudFormation template. To indicate the value for a property of the .NET attribute is meant to reference another CloudFormation resource prefix the value with @. Here is an example of the Role for the Lambda function to reference an IAM role defined in the CloudFormation template as LambdaRoleParameter


  public class Functions
  {
      [LambdaFunction( Role="@LambdaRoleParameter")]
      [RestApi("/plus/{x}/{y}")]
      public int Plus(int x, int y)
      {
          return x + y;
      }
  }

  "CloudCalculatorFunctionsAddGenerated": {
    "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
    "Metadata": {
      "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
      "SyncedEvents": [
        "RootGet"
      ]
    },
    "Properties": {
      "Runtime": "dotnet6",

...
      "Role": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "LambdaRoleParameter",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  },



Re-read my question. I've already tried the placeholder technique and it failed for me.
